# Algorithm to find a low cost path that visits specific nodes in a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

How to find the minimum (or close to minimum) cost path that visits a subset of nodes within a graph? What algorithms can I use?

I googled and found: http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node181.html

But the problem doesn't look like a minimum-cost spanning trees.

This is because the subset of nodes that I want to visit is not all of the nodes in a graph.

Sometimes there is no direct path between a node that I want to visit with any other nodes that I want to visit.

This means creating a subgraph that contains only the nodes I want to visit won't help because I definitely have to go through some of the nodes that I dont want to visit.

Comment: I guess... I could 1. Find the shortest path between any pairs of nodes that I want to visit. 2. Create a new graph between the nodes that I want, with edge that has cost representing the shortest path found in last step. 3. Find minimum-cost spanning tree.

Comment: Even if you subset of nodes includes all nodes, a spanning tree is not quite a path. However, you seem to apply that minimum spanning tree will solve your problem in the case in which your subset contains all nodes. Can you clarify that?

Comment: I can't. You are right that a tree isn't a minimal path. I don't know what algorithm can work. Didn't take computer science class and just self studied. Worst case is to double every costs for going into a dead end and then walk back.

Comment: Does your problem turn in this case into Hamiltonian Path or TSP (Traveling Salesman Problem)? If so, it's NP-hard.

Comment: Well... can also find the shortest path between the ends of every branch of the tree. After that if any ends have an odd number of these new paths, do something else.

Comment: If you don't have too many nodes, you can always just try all possibilities.

Comment: Brute forcing over all possibilities ... that sounds depressing. ok. i might do that after finding the minimal spanning tree and the shortest path between the end of the branches of the tree.

Comment: It seems that your problem is equivalent to TSP, so you can look for algorithms for this classical problem.

Comment: Are you looking for less complexity or just the algorithm?

Comment: just algorithm .